# Subtract length element two columns

Tags: bash

I've a file from which I get two columns: `cut -d $'\t' -f 4,5 file.txt`

Now I would like to get the difference in length of each element between column 1 and 2.

Input from cut command

```
A   T
AA  T
AC  TC
A   CT
```

What I would expect

```
0
1
0
-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`.

```
awk ' {print length($1) - length($2)} ' cutoutput.txt
```

Or `awk` on the original file you can simply do:

```
awk ' {print length($4) - length($5)} ' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do this only with `awk` without using `cut`. Since you don't have the original input file, I would use the following with a `|` to your cut command:

```
 cut -d $'\t' -f 4,5 file.txt | \
 awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) s=length($i)-length($NF); printf s"\n"}'
```